# Click event is not triggers from the select onchange event in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to implement click on the file input element in react based on the value selected. I below code is working fine on Linux - chrome but not working properly on windows chrome.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "upload") {
      this.fileExplorer.click();
    }
  }
  openFileExplorer(e) {
    this.fileExplorer.click();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.openFileExplorer.bind(this)}>Open</button>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
          <option key="none">None</option>
          <option key="upload">upload</option>
        </select>

        <input
          type="file"
          accept=".json"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          ref={input => (this.fileExplorer = input)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Working example on linux https://codesandbox.io/s/2wl95onqor?fontsize=14

Comment: button onclick is working fine but select onChange is not working in safari browser

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
this.openFileExplorer = this.openFileExplorer.bind(this);
```

this line should add end of the constructor.

```
<button onClick={this.openFileExplorer}>Open</button>
<select onChange={this.handleChange}
```

You should change these lines like this. I hope it will work (i'm using macos)
You can check this link;
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: button onclick is working fine, but unfortunately, select onchange is not working om macos and safari browser